# Setting up gradle org.sonarqube plugin sonar analysis task (sonarqube) in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

As per the [recent announcement](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/important-changes-to-gradle-sonarqube-support/10252) on Gradle forum, the [Sonar Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sonar_plugin.html) and [Sonar Runner Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html) are being deprecated in favor of the [SonarQube plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube). Can someone share any links (documentation or blogs) that demonstrate setting this up in Jenkins. I tried this on the local setup and gradle [sonarqube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle#AnalyzingwithGradle-Skippinganalysisofaproject) task works great.

Should we continue to use the "Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis" (from [Jenkins-Sonar](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Jenkins+Plugin) plugin) build step in a freestyle Jenkins job? With the default settings, it doesn't infer mandatory information like `sonar.projectKey`, `sonar.projectName`, `sonar.projectVersion`, `sonar.sources` from the build.gradle file. To provide it manually for a multi-module project is painful (particularly for sonar.libraries and sonar.binaries). One could think to generate a sonar-project.properties file as part of a custom gradle task that will subsequently be used by the Standalone Sonar analysis step.

However, it seems that this a generic requirement and I feel that there might be a simpler way out in in the Jenkins-Sonar plugin. Could someone familiar with the Jenkins-Sonar Plugin shed some light on it?

System info:

```
Gradle 2.5
Jenkins 1.560
SonarQube 4.5
SonarQube Gradle Plugin 1.0
Sonar Runner 2.3
Jenkins Sonar Plugin 2.2
JDK 1.8
Linux 2.6
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I did not want to put the database username and password of the remote sonarqube instance in my gradle build file and hence don't want to use the existing 'sonarqube' task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are referring to the following improvement that we want to do on the Jenkins SonarQube plugin: [SONARJNKNS-217](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJNKNS-217)

This should come sooner or later. In the meantime, you're right, there's no easier way than what you described - unfortunately.